# VS2015 node_modules Issue

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS2015 Community Edition in my windows 10 and trying to build one web application which was developed in VS2010, while build, it is creating a folder called node_modules and lot of sub folders and files, this causes an issue says: “The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.” Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node_modules` is where `npm` dependencies are stored for Node.js applications. Prior to npm v3 the dependency structure was nested and would result in some very deep file paths depending on the library. In npm v3, the dependency structure was changed to a flat structure. This reduces the nesting and should eliminate this issue almost entirely.

I would upgrade your npm to version 3+ and then delete your `node_modules` directory and then run `npm install` within that directory in `cmd.exe`.

You can upgrade your `npm` using [`npm-windows-upgrade`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade) or by running the following command in Powershell or Cygwin (Make sure to `Run as Administrator`)

`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Comment: Worked, Thanks :) but it is taking too long to build